# Levenshtein algorithm - fail-fast if edit distance is bigger than a given threshold

Tags: algorithm, delphi, levenshtein-distance

For the Levenshtein algorithm I have found [this implementation for Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580241/how-can-i-compute-a-difference-between-two-strings/10593797#10593797).

I need a version which stops as soon as a maximum distance is hit, and return the distance found so far.

My first idea is to check the current result after every iteration:

```
for i := 1 to n do
    for j := 1 to m do
    begin
      d[i, j] := Min(Min(d[i-1, j]+1, d[i,j-1]+1), d[i-1,j-1]+Integer(s[i] <> t[j]));

      // check   
      Result := d[n, m];
      if Result > max then
      begin
        Exit;
      end; 

    end;
```

Comment: That's no good. You assign to `d[i,j]`, but then test `d[n,m]`. Also, `ord()` would be more normal than `Integer()`, but I would prefer an explicit use of `IfThen()`. And result won't be assigned if n or m are less than 1.

Comment: I see, the usage of Min makes it hard to optimize before the end of both loops.

Answer (score 5):

I gather what you want is to find the levenstein distance, if it is below `MAX`, right?

If so, reaching a value larger than `MAX` is not enough, since it only means that *some* path is longer than that, but not that there exists no shorter path. To make sure no path shorter than `MAX` can be found, one has to monitor the minimum possible length of a path until the current point, i.e. the minimum over a column in the distance table.

I'm not good at Delphi, but I think the code should look something like this:

```
for i := 1 to n do
begin;
    min := MAX + 1
    for j := 1 to m do
    begin;
      d[i, j] := Min(Min(d[i-1, j]+1, d[i,j-1]+1), d[i-1,j-1]+Integer(s[i] <> t[j]));
      min := Min(min, d[i,j])
    end;
    if min >= MAX then
        Exit;
end;
```