# Levenshtein-Damerau Distance-Calculation with a Max-Distance-of-Interest Bound

Tags: algorithm, optimization, levenshtein-distance, edit-distance

Consider the **C#** implementation of the LD-distance calculation-algorithm suggested on [this Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance).

I'd like to extend it with a capability to abort the calculation-process in case a certain (pre-defined) distance-threshold has already been exceeded.

This **conceptual** optimization-approach was suggested by Alex Martelli on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183149/most-efficient-way-to-calculate-levenshtein-distance).

The question is: How can this solution be implemented over the suggested C# solution?
{ Side-Note: Function should return the maximal distance found until its return.  }

Thanks much.

Comment: @Qnan: Try **it**? If you refer to Alex's suggested solution - although I understand it conceptually, I don't know how to implement it, and specifically - on the mentioned C# implementation. I found an answer of yours to a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735576/levenshtein-algorithm-fail-fast-if-edit-distance-is-bigger-than-a-given-thresh) regarding a certain Delphi implementation, but could not port it to the C# impl. under discussion, nor did I find how to retrieve the maximum distance found, to be returned by the function. Your advise would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that you don't really understand how the algorithm works. Try to find a good manual on dynamic programming, or something more elaborate on edit distance - the thing you want to do is fairly trivial.

Comment: @YanRaf SO is a QA site, so people are expected to ask *specific* questions. If you don't quite understand the algorithm, look up a more detailed explanation, if you are not comfortable coding in C# -- find out more about the language or use another one instead. Please don't take this as criticism, but as a clarification.